# set loader on a particular div during document.ready to window.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

The problem: there's a lot of JavaScript calculation done to calculate `width` of a `div` after the "ready" state. I'd like to set such a loader time between `document.ready` and `document.load` on a `div`, so that it waits for the final `width` and then shows properly, meaning that its width hang for sometime which is its load time.

If you could not understand my question then please comment on this question.

Comment: jquery will fire events in the order you added them.

Comment: Is it large load page time that you'd like to avoid? Do you mean that you'd like to load all the page the certain `div` and load that one afterwards?

Comment: yes I want to set a loader image overlay while page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As we know ready function call before load function so we can set set loader over loading div and remove this div after load.
- loader div should be relative because overlay div will be absolute to show only on that div
- so simple hide overlay div after load the window

```js
jQuery(window).load(function(){
                             
  // THIS IS ORIGINAL CODE  
  
  //jQuery('.loader_main_overlay').css('display','none');
  // Alternate way to show loader in this example not exact way
      jQuery('.loader_main_overlay').fadeOut(2000);
   });
```

```css
.loader_main{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  }
.loader_main_overlay{
  position:absolute;
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  background-image:url('http://bildbearbeitung.onl/images/ui/load1.gif');
  background-color: #ccc;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="loader_main">
  <div class="loader_main_overlay">
      
  </div>
   <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/112576/pexels-photo-112576.jpeg" />
</div>
</body>
```